# Using dependency injection on class having parameterized constructor

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have a custom class which has a parameterized constructor

```
@Component
public class ExtractDataFromImage implements ExtractData{

    private Map<String, Boolean> selectedOptions;
    private BufferedImage image;
    
    @Autowired
    private TesseractService tesseractService;
    
    public ExtractDataFromImage(
            Map<String, Boolean> selectedOptions, 
            BufferedImage image,
            TesseractService tesseractService
            ) {
        this.selectedOptions = selectedOptions;
        this.image = image;
        this.tesseractService = tesseractService;
    }
    
    @Override
    public Map<String, ArrayList<String>> extractData() {
        //code
    }
}
```

So there are 3 parameters required at the time of instantiation. If I want to add this class as a dependency, I found that there is no direct way to do this in Spring.

I am aware that I can simply create a new instance of my class and use it's methods. But I am not finding any direct way to inject this class in my another class, which is a Rest controller.

Thing to note: All 3 parameters need to passed at runtime. I cannot use them from properties file

Even if there is no direct way in Spring, I would like to know what is the best way to define a dependency on this class and also create a new instance using the parameterized constructor

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a Spring [constructor dependency injection](https://reflectoring.io/constructor-injection/).
There are 3 ways to inject your dependency in Spring: **class field**, **contructor** and by a **setter method**.

The best and recommanded way is the constructor dependency injection.
In your case, you have to set an `@Autowired` annotation on your constructor (which is not mandatory since Spring 4.3) and remove the `@Autowired` annotation from your field `private TesseractService tesseractService;`.

```
@Autowired
public ExtractDataFromImage(
            Map<String, Boolean> selectedOptions, 
            BufferedImage image,
            TesseractService tesseractService
            ) {
        this.selectedOptions = selectedOptions;
        this.image = image;
        this.tesseractService = tesseractService;
}
```

```
@RestController
public class YourController {

    private ExtractDataFromImage edfi;

    @Autowired
    public YourController(ExtractDataFromImage edfi) {
        this.edfi = edfi;
    }
}
```

Comment: What I want to know is how to inject ExtractDataFromImage in another class. I can specify in my Rest Controller that I have a dependency on ExtractDataFromImage class, but it will only invoke default no-args constructor. I want to pass values to this parameterized constructor in my Rest Controller.

Comment: Create a constructor in your controller and inject your `ExtractDataFromImage`. I have updated the answer.